# feedburner plugin for WP 3.5

Tags: php, plugins, feedburner

I was using FD Feedburner Plugin for feeds redirection to feedburner, but now after updating to WP 3.5 it stops working. Is there any feedburner plugin which forks for WP 3.5 ?

Comment: I would sooner try to fix the plugin than find a new one altogether, what's the problem with it?

Comment: It is just not redirecting that is it.

Comment: Can I please know the reason of down votes ?

Comment: SO users prefer questions that are the last draw. It seems you haven't tried anything to solve the problem yourself. Can you narrow down why the plugin isn't working? Are there any errors, what exactly isn't happening now that used to happen? Add these details to your questions and the votes might get rectified.

Comment: Sidenote, I haven't downvoted you.

Comment: Well I see no reason for downvote .. anyway .... there is no specific error there is nothing to track ... I see this issue exists and there are other people complaining about it on the plugin page on wordpress. Thats why I am looking for another plugin and don't want to fix this one as I have no PHP knowledge,

Comment: At a guess, the downvotes are as a result of the question not demonstrating prior effort, as @Nicholas says. "Stops working" isn't specific either - do you get errors? Anything in your PHP logs? etc.

Comment: @halfer I actually went and downloaded the plugin, installed a feed and attempted to run it. The plugin failed silently. No PHP errors generated, in the logs or elsewhere. After 30 minutes of digging into the plugin code, I decided it was the author's problem. There's been a thread in the support forum for the plugin for 2 months now with no response.

Comment: @Nicholas - good effort, +1. OP, can you downgrade to the previous WP version? Not ideal, but at least you know everything works.

Answer (score 1):

[Wordpress Codex - Feedburner](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_FeedBurner)

Use the ones listed on this page, and in the future use [Wordpress StackExchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) for questions about Wordpress.